# Problem with Curl of $M\hat{i} + N\hat{j}$

Tags: curl

When I take the curl of above vector I get $\partial N/\partial x$ - $\partial M/\partial y$ . But if I do take the curl in 3×3 matrix then something different comes back (As I'm in mobile I'm unable to write this in mathjax). Then what is real curl of the vector? Where is the mistake I have made.

Comment: Isn't curl only defined in $\mathbb{R}^3$? You have a two dimensional vector there.

Comment: @Sobi a $\mathbb{R}^2$ vector field which can have curl or can rotate as if the vector field had been $-y\hat{i} +x\hat{j} $ then curl would be 2$\hat{k}$

Comment: I see. In that case, it would be good if you could write how you obtained the curl to be $\partial N / \partial x - \partial M / \partial y$.

Comment: @Sobi if we use 2×2 matrix of curl then we'll get it.

Comment: What kind of a $2 \times 2$ matrix?

Comment: @Sobi see https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-divergence-and-curl-of-a-vector-field-in-two-dimensions&ved=2ahUKEwiI2-qx5-TcAhUKto8KHTm5BKkQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw1HjAX5LHeesAOxg8YsLX3Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the definition from the link that you presented in the comments, one gets
$$ \text{curl}(F) = \left(\partial_x N - \partial_y M\right) \hat{k}. $$
Here it is assumed that $M=M(x,y)$ and $N=N(x,y)$ are *independent of $z$*.

On the other hand, I'm assuming that the $3 \times 3$ matrix (or rather, determinant) you are referring to is
$$
\text{curl}(F) = \begin{vmatrix}
\hat i & \hat j & \hat k \\
\partial_x & \partial_y & \partial_z \\
F_i & F_j & F_k
\end{vmatrix},
$$
which, for $F = M\hat i + N \hat j + 0\hat k$, becomes
\begin{align}
\text{curl}(F) &= \begin{vmatrix}
\hat i & \hat j & \hat k \\
\partial_x & \partial_y & \partial_z \\
M & N & 0
\end{vmatrix}
= (0 - \partial_z N)\hat i - (0-\partial_z M)\hat j + (\partial_x N -\partial_y M)\hat k = (\partial_x N -\partial_y M)\hat k,
\end{align}
where $\partial_z M = \partial_z N = 0$ since $M$ and $N$ were assumed to be independent of $z$.

Comment: Well thanks man... i got it.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that curl of a vector field in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and not a scalar. Now, **if** we assume both M and N are not functions of $z$ but only of $x$ and $y$ we get your solution but there is a $\hat{k}$ missing. If you evaluate the curl matrix (3x3) taking that your z-component of the vector field is zero **and** that both M and N are not functions of $z$ but only of $x$ and $y$ then you should get back the same, as rest of the terms go to zero!